# Android application displays black screen after returning from another activity wilth result

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult, android-debug

I have a basic Android application developed for Android 4.3.1 API18.
In my application I startActivityForResult using the following code:

```
footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = 
            new Intent(ThisActivityClass.this,OtherActivityClass.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
});
```

The new Activity runs as expected and returns result to the first Activity using the following code:

```
final Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent data = new Intent();

        data.putExtra("A", "DONT_CARE");        

        setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Back in the calling Activity a result is successfully received in the onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult
  (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        switch(requestCode)
        {
        case 1:
            ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem(data);
            //...Saving Data from Intent
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

So far so good.
After that the current activity gets called to its methods in the following order, which means that everything is fine:
1. onStart()
2. onResume()
 Note: onPause\onStop werent called!

And from here the problem appears - The simulator shows a black screen - the action bar is visible.

And The debugger stops on the Choreographer.class in the doCallbacks method **on its last line, on the closing Brackets**:

```
void doCallbacks(int callbackType, long frameTimeNanos) {
    CallbackRecord callbacks;
    synchronized (mLock) {
        // We use "now" to determine when callbacks become due because it's possible
        // for earlier processing phases in a frame to post callbacks that should run
        // in a following phase, such as an input event that causes an animation to start.
        final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        callbacks = mCallbackQueues[callbackType].extractDueCallbacksLocked(now);
        if (callbacks == null) {
            return;
        }
        mCallbacksRunning = true;
    }
    try {
        for (CallbackRecord c = callbacks; c != null; c = c.next) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "RunCallback: type=" + callbackType
                        + ", action=" + c.action + ", token=" + c.token
                        + ", latencyMillis=" + (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - c.dueTime));
            }
            c.run(frameTimeNanos);
        }
    } finally {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mCallbacksRunning = false;
            do {
                final CallbackRecord next = callbacks.next;
                recycleCallbackLocked(callbacks);
                callbacks = next;
            } while (callbacks != null);
        }
    }
}
```

LogCat shows the following output, pay attention to the calls for onActivityResult, onStart, onResume shown at the end of the log:

```
03-22 08:54:26.308: D/gralloc_goldfish(1224): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-22 08:54:26.588: I/Choreographer(1224): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 08:54:46.268: I/Lab-UserInterface(1224): Entered footerView.OnClickListener.onClick()
03-22 08:54:46.398: I/Lab-UserInterface(1224): ToDoManagerActivity entered onPause
03-22 08:54:51.039: I/Choreographer(1224): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 08:54:52.759: I/Choreographer(1224): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 08:54:56.249: I/Choreographer(1224): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 08:54:58.758: I/Lab-UserInterface(1224): Entered submitButton.OnClickListener.onClick()
03-22 08:54:59.261: I/Lab-UserInterface(1224): Entered onActivityResult()
03-22 08:56:45.298: I/Lab-UserInterface(1224): ToDoManagerActivity entered onStart
03-22 08:56:45.298: I/Lab-UserInterface(1224): ToDoManagerActivity entered onResume
03-22 08:56:45.338: I/Choreographer(1224): Skipped 27628 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 08:56:45.489: D/dalvikvm(1224): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 108K, 6% free 3711K/3936K, paused 37ms, total 53ms
```

I tried many things and couldn't come up with a solution:
1. Couldn't find a solution online
2. I wrapped each method with a try catch blocks

How would you describe the problem? 
Did the Activity lost focus (I think not)?
The foreground application entered a weired state?
What other debugging tools may be used to locate the problem?
And on top, did you came across this problem\know how to solve it?

Regards,
hoshmy

Comment: Exactly as the log message says. Your main (UI) thread is too busy. This prevents Android from updating the display. You have some code running on the main thread that is either in an infinite loop or you have a deadlock somewhere.

Comment: What does `c.run(frameTimeNanos);` do? And if this is being called on the main (UI) thread this may be your culprit.

Comment: All the code from the Chow much about it.oreographer is pure Android code - I dont know much about it.
Any way my problem was solved - I had an uncaught exception which led to the activity not drawing itself and therefore the unresponsive black screen. 
Unexpectadly while running in debug it was hard to receive verbose information about the problem, while when running in "Run As" mode I got more helpfull information.
When In doubt warp all you methods with try-catch!